# How To Detect If An Actor Is Hit In Unreal Engine C++?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

I'm new to Unreal Engine. I'm trying to create a basic game where you control a ball and roll around, trying not to fall out of a tube and stuff. My ball looks like this:

PlayerBall.h

```
#pragma once

#include "CoreMinimal.h"
#include "GameFramework/Pawn.h"
#include "PlayerBall.generated.h"

UCLASS()
class ROLLINGBALL_API APlayerBall : public APawn
{
    GENERATED_BODY()

public:
    // Sets default values for this pawn's properties
    APlayerBall();

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category="Mesh")
    UStaticMeshComponent* Mesh;

    UPROPERTY(VisibleAnywhere, Category="Camera")
    class UCameraComponent* Camera;

protected:
    // Called when the game starts or when spawned
    void BeginPlay() override;

public: 
    // Called every frame
    void Tick(float DeltaTime) override;

    // Called to bind functionality to input
    void SetupPlayerInputComponent(class UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) override;

};
```

PlayerBall.cpp

```
#include "PlayerBall.h"
#include "Camera/CameraComponent.h"

// Sets default values
APlayerBall::APlayerBall() {
    // Set this pawn to call Tick() every frame.  You can turn this off to improve performance if you don't need it.
    PrimaryActorTick.bCanEverTick = true;

    Mesh = CreateDefaultSubobject<UStaticMeshComponent>(TEXT("Mesh"));
    const ConstructorHelpers::FObjectFinder<UStaticMesh> SphereRef(TEXT("StaticMesh'/Game/StarterContent/Shapes/Shape_Sphere.Shape_Sphere'"));
    Mesh->SetStaticMesh(SphereRef.Object);
    Mesh->SetSimulatePhysics(true);
    Mesh->SetEnableGravity(true);
    SetRootComponent(Mesh);

    Camera = CreateDefaultSubobject<UCameraComponent>(TEXT("Camera"));
    Camera->SetRelativeLocation(FVector(-500.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f));
    Camera->SetupAttachment(RootComponent);

    AutoPossessPlayer = EAutoReceiveInput::Player0;
}

// Called when the game starts or when spawned
void APlayerBall::BeginPlay() {
    Super::BeginPlay();

}

// Called every frame
void APlayerBall::Tick(float DeltaTime) {
    Super::Tick(DeltaTime);

}

// Called to bind functionality to input
void APlayerBall::SetupPlayerInputComponent(UInputComponent* PlayerInputComponent) {
    Super::SetupPlayerInputComponent(PlayerInputComponent);

}
```

I also have some other obstacles and floor. However, I also want some obstacle that kills you if it hits you. I want some sort of method in the `APlayerBall` class that is called when it is hit, then I can check the type of actor that is hit. What can I do? What component do I use?n I looked for an hour in the documentation, but I couldn't find anything.

I tried adding the `RecieveHit` method, however it says that it doesn't override from a super class. I added it like this:

```
void ReceiveHit
(
class UPrimitiveComponent * MyComp,
AActor * Other,
class UPrimitiveComponent * OtherComp,
bool bSelfMoved,
FVector HitLocation,
FVector HitNormal,
FVector NormalImpulse,
const FHitResult & Hit
) override;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to be doing is binding to the AActor::OnActorHit event with OnActorHit.AddDynamic(this, &FunctionPointer).

The RecieveHit function is internal and will be what broadcasts this event.

Answer (score 1):

That would be [AActor::ReceiveHit](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/API/Runtime/Engine/GameFramework/AActor/ReceiveHit/index.html), since PlayerBall inherits from APawn which inherits from AActor.

Comment: I tried copy and pasting the method, but when I added `override` to the end I got an error saying it doesn't override from a super class. Was this method deleted or something? I edited my question to show what I did.

Comment: I just looked into the source code and saw that it wasn't marked as `virtual`. So overriding it won't even make a difference.

Comment: Ah, sorry--ReceiveHit is an **event**, so you don't override the function, you [bind](https://docs.unrealengine.com/en-US/Programming/UnrealArchitecture/Delegates/index.html#bindingdelegates) to it.

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, but I don't seem to understand it. The ReceiveHit method doesn't seem to be marked as a Delegate, and where do I get the Delegate object to actually bind it?